# Serverless SignalR authentication with JWT in Azure Function

Tags: signalr, azure-functions

I am using a `SignalRConnectionInfo` input binding in an Azure function. In this binding I need to provide the `userId` of the current principal, however by default the Azure function only supports the use of pre-defined headers from App Service Authentication, as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service#authenticated-tokens), and in the below example:

```cs
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest req, 
  [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "foo", UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
  return connectionInfo;
}
```

As I am not using App Service authentication, and do not wish to, this is not suitable for my needs.

What I do currently have is a JWT which the user provides to an API we host in another App Service in order to authenticate the request and identify themselves. How can I amend the `UserId` property of the `SignalRConnectionInfo` binding to retrieve the UserId from the claims within that JWT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a way to extract information from a JWT using binding expressions.

Instead, you will have to use [Runtime Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) to first extract the information from the JWT and then use it in the binding to get the SignalR Connection Information.

Here's a functional example where the JWT is retrieved from the `Authorization` header, validated, then applied to the `SignalRConnectionInfo` attribute.

```csharp
[FunctionName("Negotiate")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "negotiate")] HttpRequest req,
  IBinder binder)
{
  if (!req.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
    return new UnauthorizedResult();

  var principal = TryGetPrincipal(req.Headers["Authorization"].ToString());
  if (principal == null) 
    return new UnauthorizedResult();

  var connectionInfo = await binder.BindAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>(new SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute
  {
    HubName = _hubName,
    UserId = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
  });
  return new OkObjectResult(connectionInfo);
}

public ClaimsPrincipal TryGetPrincipal(string token) 
{
  // implementation varies based on authorization type...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you mind if I edit your answer to include the functioning code in order to help future visitors?

Comment: Sure. No Problem. Thanks!